# Best Way to Optimize Insert/ Updating Large # Rows Against Large Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, insert-update

I will probably cross-post this but I assume it's a common problem - didn't find anything quite right in my search.

My task is this --- I have a data source streaming a source of "updates" and "new tickets" to a MySQL collection of tickets. Each ticket has a unique Ticket_ID.

Essentially, I need to take these updates and do an insert/ update against a table of tickets. Simple enough.

The problem is that every day, there are 3,000 rows to insert/update against this ever-increasing-list that is currently at 300,000 and can probably expand to 1 million.

Luckily, after 30 days, I know a ticket cannot be updated again, so perhaps can move that to an archive. Still, that's 3000 rows a day against a month of data, which is usually 90,000 rows. That simply takes a lot of time. I haven't checked the exact figure but maybe 30 minutes to an hour, maybe longer.

How do I optimize this process of insert/ update, which by definition, has to lookup each incoming Ticket_ID against the database of existing Ticket_IDs?

Is the insert/ update process simply the best that there is?

The main problem is that insert/ update process can only have one running at a time --- as oppose to having 10+ (just insert) processes running simultaneously and then 1 delete duplicates process following.

Or is there a creative way like ... find ticket_ids where count(*) > 1 -- delete the one with the older timestamp -- that could save me some time?

I know this is a complicated question but it seems like a common problem. Thanks.

Comment: if you don't need instant gratification you can stream your new data to a staging table with no indexes or foreign keys.  Then at some point, write to your real table from your staging table.

Comment: 3000 rows a day, that's only 125 per hour. Maybe spend more time talking about your process. Even if you process them all at once at it takes 30 minutes, what's the issue with that? When do you query this data? Are you using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`?

Comment: Hmm I wouldn't necessarily have an issue with a 30 minute process that ran once a day, though it would limit the data to daily updates, but I can live with that. The main issue is I think my database net write timeout is capped at 60 seconds --- I wouldn't think that's a factor, but it's possible the connection is closing before this full process can be completed. I'm not sure.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE and show us the slow process.

Comment: Can't you deal with the 'dup' that the `COUNT(*)` is trying to catch as you do the insert/update?  And doesn't it have a `UNIQUE` (or `PRIMARY`) KEY to make it very efficient to deal with?  If not, can we move that direction?